# series divergence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{k^2})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Using the limit compression test

$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{k^2})}}{\frac{1}{k}}=\infty$$

But is there a smaller series that diverge? so we can use it to prove that $\sqrt{\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{k^2})}$ diverge?

Comment: I don't  get it: $\;\frac1{k^2}\rightarrow 0\implies \arctan\frac1{k^2}\rightarrow\arctan0=0\implies \sqrt{\arctan\frac1{k^2}}\rightarrow0\;$ Why do you think it diverges?

Comment: I guess your question is really $\sum \sqrt{\arctan(1/k^2)}$ diverges. And the $1/k$ you chose is the correct order, as $\arctan(1/k^2) \sim 1/k^2$ for large $k$

Comment: I think the OP talks about $\sum_k\sqrt{ \arctan(k^{-2})}$.

Comment: The limit as $k\to\infty$ is $1$, not $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have fixed the question

Comment: Actually, if you examine the proof of the validity of the limit comparison test, you will see that it does produce a series of smaller terms to compare with.

Answer (score 5):

From
$$
\arctan x > \frac{x}2,\qquad x\in (0,1),
$$ you get
$$
\arctan \frac1{k^2} > \frac12\:\frac1{k^2},\qquad k=1,2,\ldots
$$ and
$$
\sqrt{\arctan \frac1{k^2}} > \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\:\frac1{k},\qquad k=1,2,\ldots
$$ thus, for $N \geq1$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^N\sqrt{\arctan \frac1{k^2}} > \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\:\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{k}
> $$

and the initial series is **divergent** as is the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\arctan\frac1{x^2}}}{\frac1{x}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac2{x^3}\frac1{1+\frac1{x^4}}\frac1{2\sqrt{\arctan\frac1{x^2}}}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^4}{(x^4+1)2x\sqrt{\arctan\frac1{x^2}}}=1$$

and thus the series $\;\sum\sqrt{\arctan\frac1{n^2}}\;$ converges iff the series $\;\sum\frac1{n}\;$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

hint you can use $arctan(1/k^2)\approx 1/k^2$ for small k which can be proved by Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a series that diverges and has smaller terms than $a_k=1/k$, try $b_k=1/(k\ln k)$, which in series from $k=2$ diverges due to the integral test.